# List of Anchors for Sep31 and SEP24?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

Is there a list of anchors available that I can access to see if I'm interested in using any of them? It is proving rather tedious to find anchors through a google search. I am already making API calls on Horizon, just not sure if anything is made available to help with this.

I'm specifically looking for Anchors that can process USD from a credit card in exchange for XLM (user pays USD and gets XLM), which I can then use to facilitate/transfer other assets.

Answer (score 0):

[stellar.expert](https://stellar.expert/directory?tag%5B%5D=anchor) is curating a list of anchors. You may find that useful.